# How to execute the next click only when previous click finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, continuous

My HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Testing Paragraph</p>
    <span>Testing Span</span>
    <div class="content">This is the main content of this div</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('p').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vs5DX/

As you can see from the demo, the content will slide up and slide down when you click the paragraph. The problem is that if I click the paragraph for many times very fast then it's continuously going up and down without clicking.

I've tried:

```
$(this).parent().find('.content').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
```

But it's even worse when the animation stop going. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**:not**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude the current [**:animated**](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) elements:

```
$('p').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.content:not(:animated)').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vs5DX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a variable:

```
varClicked = false;
```

on slideDown make it as true, allow slideUp only if it is true, on SlideUp, make it false again